# Embedded C, LPC expresso, remove "path not found" warning

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I am using LPCxpresso, Eclipse based to develop some embedded software on a hardware project I am designing.

I am getting "Include path not found" warnings.  These includes are not required and my code compiles.  But I am trying to strip down code to what is actually required and can't find where these paths are being defined in the project.

I can't simply delete these files from the project tree nor find them defined in project settings.

I have inherited the code and some of the hardware from a previous project however this code was very bloated and contained a lot of dead code by which I mean code that can never be called, either as entire functions or just unreachable: such as code after an endless loop such as:

```
    while (1) {
        /* Do something */
    }

    /* Now do something else */[
```

Assume the comments shown above are actual code as this is just to illustrate the point.

The original code was originally several interlinked projects.  I now have it reduced to a single project to simplify future maintenance.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas I how I remove these warnings

Comment: The IDE is not finding the path from `c:\users\....\fatfs\inc` So I guess the project base directory is not correct.

Comment: Have you posted this in the NXP technical community forum? https://community.nxp.com/community/mcuxpresso/mcuxpresso-ide?tid=communitymcuxpresso

Comment: @RishikeshRaje The code no-longer exists so should not be referenced as part of the project, I'm trying to remove the reference.@KeithSmith Yes 3 days ago no response yet.

Comment: @KeithSmith From the images, i can see that the `...\fatfs\inc` is there in the includes section. There should be some settings in the IDE to remove it from there. maybe this link will help https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/167423/

Comment: Just to be sure, you say you can't find them in you project settings. So they aren't under "Right click on Klio" -> "Properties" -> "C/C++ Build" -> "Settings" -> "MCU C Compiler" -> "Includes"? If so you can delete them there.

Comment: @RoelBalink I don't have that as an option.  "Klio" -> "Properties" -> "C/C++ Build" -> "Settings" -> "ToolSettings" -> "Includes" only lists one directory and  "Klio" -> "Properties" -> "C/C++ Build" -> "MCU Settings"  only lists processor types. I think this may be a bug and may need to upgrade to their newer "MCUXpresso" and create a new workspace file by file.

Comment: I don't think upgrading to MUCXpresso will make a big difference. You could also try to manually remove the links from the .cproject file. The .cproject file should be in (I think) the root of your project folder. Then open it in notepad, and search if you can find those url's there and delete them. Offcouse make a backup of the original .cproject file before changing it in case you make a mistake.